# Are tinted sprites actually being batched in newer versions of Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

Since my day one in Unity development, I've seen tips and stuff saying that we should never tint sprites. If we want sprites of different colors, create them and place them in the same texture, and then swap in the differently-colored sprites.

The reasoning is that tinting sprites will break batching.

I have created a small demo.

---

**Situation 1**

[image: Situation 1]

The same square sprite is used in 6 game objects. No surprise here. In the stats, there is 1 batch. 5 are saved by batching.

---

**Situation 2**

[image: Situation 2]

The same square sprite is used in 6 game objects again, but this time, all of them are tinted red with the same color value.

**Shouldn't this be breaking batching already?**

---

**Situation 3**

[image: Situation 3]

For the sake of completeness, I tinted the square sprites with different colors. Still, we have 1 batch and 5 saved. Nothing's changed.

---

**Additional information**

1. I captured Situation 1 & 2 during a single play through, and situation 3 in a separate play through.
2. I tried tinting the sprites **directly in the editor** by changing the "Color" field of `SpriteRenderer` and **through scripts** by changing `SpriteRenderer.color`. The results are the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "tinting" ? Do you change the albedo ? The batching is a process of optimization on the textures loading, changing the shader properties may won't affect it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant changing the SpriteRenderer.color property. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing color of sprites on the `SpriteRenderer` component shouldn't break batching. What breaks batching is when you change the SpriteRenderer's sprite, the material or even when you try to access the material with `SpriteRenderer.material` property.

For example,

This **breaks** batching:

```
SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
sr.material.color = Color.red;
```

because you are accessing the material. It will create new material instance when you access the material property for the first time.

---

This **will not** break batching:

```
SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
sr.color = Color.red;
```

It will not because it is not accessing the `material` property. Even though it will not break batching, one issue with it is performance. It affects performance when you do this.

Comment: You said "it affects performance when you do this", you mean setting the `SpriteRenderer.color` property? In the other answer, KYL3R thinks it is basically "free". I can see where that comes from, because the default value of `SpriteRenderer.color` is `Color.white` and it is sent to the GPU anyway (not sure). Since the particle system is doing that as well, can we say that whatever performance cost there might be, it is rather negligible?

Comment: Yes, setting `SpriteRenderer.color` affects performance espacially if you plan to do this every frame with many SpriteRenerers. The good side is that it won't break batching. KYL3R made and edit to his answer and most of the stuff he's talking only applies to 3D Objects(MeshRenderer). He also suggested you use MaterialPropertyBlocks to circumvent the material batching breaking I talked about but MaterialPropertyBlocks breaks batching. I really on't know about the ParticleSystem as the question is about SpriteRenderer and I have studied SpriteRenderer before.

Comment: but I think that ParticleSystem is likely implemented and optimize better than SpriteRenderer since it is expected that they have different color, size etc

Comment: Ouch, Material Property Blocks seem to break batching, I was wrong there. But using GPU Instancing you can give each a vector of data and it **will** batch, however this allows " a lot of the same " objects to be drawn. If you want different objects, stick with vertex colors.

Comment: SpriteRenderer.color should work fine if OP wants to changed the color (tint) and not break batching. GPU Instancing  is used for something else. It is used to instantiate many objects and is not supported on all devices especially mobile devices.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, tinting is basically setting a vertex color. This is done for particles, where you can set random start colors and all the particles are rendered in a single draw call. Vertex color does not change/create a new material.

Not sure how that was handled in early Unity versions, but sprites should be simple quads and therefore support vertex colors. The Sprite shader probably works the same way in terms of tinting.

In general, you are right. Changing shader properties will create a duplicate of that material, or it will change the material itself and affect all instances using the material. Did you use the tint on the sprite material, or on the spriteRenderer?

By hand, I could think of using MaterialPropertyBlocks, but maybe Unity did exactly that for sprites.

---

Some more Detail to clarify:

**A** You have "Material01.mat" - it's green. You copy this material to 10 sprites. You want to have 10 colors? You have to create 10 materials, each holding the desired color - 10 Draw calls.

You can do the same by script, just change material.color. But Unity will duplicate the materials for you. Still 10 Draw calls. Some people are confused why it breaks batching until they hear about this.

**B** You changed the RENDERERs tint. This Sprite Renderer will write the tint color into your sprites vertices (probably 4?) - using the vertex color attribute. It's basically free, because they are transmitted to the gpu anyway (afaik)

As I said above, the same is used in the Particle System, to allow rainbow particles with 1 Drawcall.

So, any particle Shader, self-written shader, or Sprite Shader should work with this. All you need is `a.albedo = c.rgb * IN.vert.color` (a bit pseudo code here)

That means, the same shader, and the same material can be used for multiple objects, having different vertex colors. That won't break batching.

You can even have different objects of any shape and vertex count, giving them different vertex colors (per vertex, like gradients etc) and it will still batch.

Check Static whenever possible, feed information into vertex colors, and for moving objects, try to keep them under 300 verts, so dynamic batching can work.

But for Sprites, unity automated this for you, you simply need to use the SpriteRenderer - that's why you don't use a quad with a texture, but a "Sprite" and a SpriteRenderer.

Again, I could be wrong and the SpriteRenderer actually uses MaterialPropertyBlocks, but it works almost the same. These variables can be set per object and do not create new DrawCalls. The variable values are used in the shader, so the material/shader is the same for multiple objects.

Comment: I changed the SpriteRenderer.color property.

All the sprite squares use the standard Sprites-Default Material.

Do you mean that duplicates of Sprites-Default will be created if I tint it, but it won't break batching?

Comment: I added some more details to my answer under the horizontal line.

Comment: This is pretty accurate, a lot techniques and "rules of thumb" get their understanding confused when using high-level APIs. To really understand the "why", would suggest OP look at OpenGL pipeline (or DirectX), and see how the graphics card handles rendering. This will give a better understanding of what is occurring at each stage, and the "how and why" these "rules" exists, and what  performance pitfalls to avoid.